# Did Hagrid Disapparate in The Philosopher's Stone?

Tags: harry-potter

In *The Philosopher's Stone,*

> Hagrid helped Harry on to the train that would take him back to the
>   Dursleys, then handed him an envelope.
>   "Yer ticket fer Hogwarts, " he said. "First o' September -- King's Cross
>   -- it's all on yer ticket. Any problems with the Dursleys, send me a
>   letter with yer owl, she'll know where to find me.... See yeh soon,
>   Harry."
>
> The train pulled out of the station. Harry wanted to watch Hagrid until
>   he was out of sight; he rose in his seat and pressed his nose against
>   the window, but he blinked and Hagrid had gone.

Having a wand is necessary to apparate, and, as we later see that Hagrid keeps the fragments of his broken wand in his umbrella, and Hagrid has his umbrella with him throughout this chapter, did Hagrid Disapparate?